# Z3: Java API for quantified formulas

Tags: z3, java

I am trying to use the JAVA API of Z3 to construct the following formula

```
    (assert (forall ((x_0 fcn_sort_2) (x_1 fcn_sort_2))
                    (=> (and (= (domain x_0) 
                                (domain x_1))
                             (forall ((y Int))
                                     (= (alpha x_0 y) 
                                        (alpha x_1 y))))))
                        (= x_0 x_1)))))
```

by the following code

```
Sort[] types1 = new Sort[2]; // for x_0 and x_1
Expr[] xs1 = new Expr[2];        
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    types1[j] = this.getZ3Sort("fcn_sort_2");        
    xs1[j] = ctx.mkConst(ctx.mkSymbol("x_" + Integer.toString(j)), types1[j]);        
}    
Sort[] types2 = new Sort[1]; // for y
Expr[] xs2 = new Expr[1];    
types2[0] = ctx.mkIntSort();
xs2[0] = ctx.mkConst(ctx.mkSymbol("y"), types2[0]);
FuncDecl alpha_fcn = this.getFuncSymbol("alpha");
Expr[] arg0 = new Expr[] { xs1[0], xs2[0] };
Expr[] arg1 = new Expr[] { xs1[1], xs2[0] };
BoolExpr 
    // (= (alpha x_0 y) (alpha x_1 y))
    body2 = ctx.mkEq(ctx.mkApp(alpha_fcn, arg0), ctx.mkApp(alpha_fcn, arg1)), 
    // forall ((y Int)) ...
    bf2 = ctx.mkForall(xs2, body2, 1, null, null, null, null); 
FuncDecl domain_fcn = this.getFuncSymbol("domain");
BoolExpr
    // (= x_0 x_1)
    eqX = ctx.mkEq(xs1[0], xs1[1]), 
    // (= (domain x_0) (domain x_1))
    eqDo = ctx.mkEq(ctx.mkApp(domain_fcn, new Expr[] {xs1[0]}), ctx.mkApp(domain_fcn, new Expr[] {xs1[1]})), 
    // (and ...)
    andNode = ctx.mkAnd(eqDo, bf2),         
    // (=> ...)
    body1 = ctx.mkImplies(andNode, eqX),
    // (forall ((x_0 ...) (x_1 ...))
    bf1 = ctx.mkForall(xs1, body1, 1, null, null, null, null);
```

where getFuncSymbol is my own function to get a FuncDecl which is declared before.

Unfortunately, I have the wrong result with "let" and "a!1"

```
(assert (forall ((x_0 fcn_sort_2) (x_1 fcn_sort_2))
  (let ((a!1 (and (= (domain_fcn_sort_2 x_0) (domain_fcn_sort_2 x_1))
                  (forall ((y Int))
                    (= (alpha_fcn_sort_2 x_0 y) (alpha_fcn_sort_2 x_1 y))))))
    (=> a!1 (= x_0 x_1)))))
```

I found that something wrong, "let ((a!1", happens at the line

```
    body1 = ctx.mkImplies(andNode, eqX)
```

Am I missing something? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let-expressions are introduced during pretty-printing in an attempt to make the output more concise. Here, it simply means that whenever the name `a!1` occurs in the output, you can replace it with `(and ...)`. Semantically, this doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Christoph.